# NMAP not mapping DOWN status

Tags: nmap

I used this command from another post and the file scan.txt only shows the servers  with UP status.  The listing should also show down status of IP. Is there a switch for that?
nmap -sn -PE -oG scan.txt 192.168.1.1 192.168.2.0/24

Any IP that is down does not show up in scan.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `-v` will show hosts with 'Down' status as well.